# PostAsync in UWP App not working (no content sent)

Tags: c#, uwp, httpclient

I'm a bit stuck,  I am trying to create a UWP App that will post XML content to a web service.  I can get this to work in a regular .net console app without an issue.  Trying to re-create this using UWP is proving to be tricky.  Using fiddler I've narrowed down that the web service end point isn't receiving my content.  It looks like the headers are setup properly the content length is sent correctly but the actual content isn't sent.  Here is the heart of the code, it crashes/throws an exception after:

```
HttpResponseMessage ResponseMessage = await request.PostAsync(requestUri, httpContent2).ContinueWith(
                                    (postTask) => postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode());
```

When I try to execute the PostASync, looking at fiddler, I'm getting:

```
HTTP/1.1 408 Request body incomplete
Date: Mon, 14 Nov 2016 15:38:53 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Timestamp: 10:38:53.430
```

The request body did not contain the specified number of bytes. Got 0, expected 617

I'm positive that I am getting content to post correct (I read it from a file, I send it to debug window to verify and it's correct).  I think it might have to do with HttpContent httpContent2 - In regular .NET I've never needed to use this  but with PostAsync I need to use it.

Any thoughts would be appreciated, thank you!

```
    public async void PostWebService()
    {


        string filePath = "Data\\postbody.txt";
        string url = "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx";

        Uri requestUri = new Uri(url); //replace your Url  

        var myClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        myClientHandler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user@acme.com", "password");

        HttpClient request = new HttpClient(myClientHandler);

        string contents = await ReadFileContentsAsync(filePath);
        Debug.WriteLine(contents);

        HttpContent httpContent2 = new StringContent(contents, Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");

        string s = await httpContent2.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine(s); //just checking to see if httpContent has the correct data

        //HttpResponseMessage ResponseMessage = await request.PostAsync(requestUri, httpContent);
        request.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 65000;



        HttpResponseMessage ResponseMessage = await request.PostAsync(requestUri, httpContent2).ContinueWith(
                                    (postTask) => postTask.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode());

        Debug.WriteLine(ResponseMessage.ToString());

    }
```

Comment: I suggest you use a proxy like Fiddler to get the whole request and see if it is correct.

Comment: I did that actually - that's how I know that it is sending the correct content size but it's not sending the actual post data.

Comment: Copied your code, I cannot reproduce your issue, your code seems to be right to me. How did you make it work in Console app? If you're using `System.Net.Http` for `HttpClient`, then the code should be the same in UWP app as it is in your console app.

Comment: Grace thank you for trying, I actually found out this is a bug this is a known bug in System.Net.Http.HttpClient when using network credentials. I'm going to post a proper response so this will help someone else.  Curious, you said it worked for you (seems strange - what version of Windows 10 are you building against?).  

I should have clarified what I meant by "working in a console app". In my test console app, I used using System.Net and HttpWebRequest.  Would be interested in finding out how you got it working.

Answer (score 2):

Well it seems like I found the root cause to my problem.  This is appears to be a known bug with System.Net.Http.HttpClient when using network authentication.  See this article [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9e137127-e0e5-4aec-a7a9-d66f5b84c70b/rtm-known-issue-systemnethttphttpclient-or-httpwebrequest-class-usage-in-a-uwp-app-throws-a?forum=Win10SDKToolsIssues)

My initial mistake was that I wasn't catching an exceptions thrown by PostAsync.  once I wrapped that inside a try/catch block I got the following exception thrown:

***“This IRandomAccessStream does not support the GetInputStreamAt method because it requires cloning and this stream does not support cloning.”***

The first paragraph of the article I linked to above states:

> When you use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class from a .NET
> framework based Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app and send a
> HTTP(s) PUT or POST request to a URI which requires Integrated Windows
> Authentication – such as Negotiate/NTLM, an exception will be thrown.
>
> The thrown exception will have an InnerException property set to the
> message:
>
> “This IRandomAccessStream does not support the GetInputStreamAt method
> because it requires cloning and this stream does not support cloning.”
>
> The problem happens because the request as well as the entity body of
> the POST/PUT request needs to be resubmitted during the authentication
> challenge. The above problem does not happen for HTTP verbs such as
> GET which do not require an entity body.
>
> This is a known issue in the RTM release of the Windows 10 SDK and we
> are tracking a fix for this issue for a subsequent release.

The recommendation and work around that worked for me was to use the **Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient** instead of **System.Net.Http.HttpClient**

Using that recommendation, the following code worked for me:

```
      string filePath = "Data\\postbody.txt";
            string url = "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx";

            Uri requestUri = new Uri(url); //replace your Url  

            string contents = await ReadFileContentsAsync(filePath);
            string search_str = txtSearch.Text;

            Debug.WriteLine("Search query:" + search_str);
            contents = contents.Replace("%SEARCH%", search_str);

            Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter hbpf = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
            Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential pcred = new Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordCredential(url, "username@acme.com", "password");
            hbpf.ServerCredential = pcred;
             
            HttpClient request = new HttpClient(hbpf);

            Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage hreqm = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage(Windows.Web.Http.HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(url));
            Windows.Web.Http.HttpStringContent hstr = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpStringContent(contents, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8, "text/xml");
            hreqm.Content = hstr;

            // consume the HttpResponseMessage and the remainder of your code logic from here.


            try
            {
                Windows.Web.Http.HttpResponseMessage hrespm = await request.SendRequestAsync(hreqm);

                Debug.WriteLine(hrespm.Content);
                String respcontent = await hrespm.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string e = ex.Message;
                Debug.WriteLine(e);
            }
```

Hopefully this is helpful to someone else hitting this issue.